# referencing style issue

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I need to submit a paper to springer journal at this [link](http://www.springer.com/computer/database+management+%26+information+retrieval/journal/10618?detailsPage=pltci_2554736).
but I have the following issue in referencing.

they require this style as the link show.
So ex: Journal article

> Gamelin FX, Baquet G, Berthoin S, Thevenet D, Nourry C, Nottin S,
>   Bosquet L (2009) Effect of high intensity intermittent training on
>   heart rate variability in prepubescent children. Eur J Appl
>   Physiol 105:731-738. doi: 10.1007/s00421-008-0955-8

but in latex for the bibtex, I got the following citation, which differs from the required one:

> Gamelin FX, Baquet G, Berthoin S, Thevenet D, Nourry C, Nottin S,
>   Bosquet L (2009) Effect of high intensity intermittent training on
>   heart rate variability in prepubescent children. European journal
>   of applied physiology 105(5):731-738

So they mention that there is a style for endnote, I export the references as .bib, but with using their style which is not the bibtex, for the exported bib file, it can't be cited at latex.

I used this for referencing:

```
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}  
\bibliography{hana}
```

`hana.bib` is the bibtex file.

`spbasic`: bibliography style provided by Springer's latex package, I didn't find the latex style equivalent for their endnote style.

Comment: The only differences I perceive are (a) the use of abbreviated versus unabbreviated journal names, (b) the presence or absence of the within-year issue number of the journal, and (c) the presence or absence of a `doi` field. Is this impression correct?

Comment: So how to get the required style?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to provide the abbreviated form of the journal's name. For sure, the file `spbasic.bst` doesn't provide a ready-made abbreviation for the journal in question. Do observe proper uppercasing, though: I'd write `journal = "European Journal of Applied Physiology,"`. Secon,d if you don't want to show the issue number, simply change the name of the field from `number` to `xnumber`. On the other hand, I see no harm in showing the number in the formatted entry. Finally, I don't think the `doi` field is required.